# Why does "f" match c* in Bash regex?

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to parse an optional argument with each letter being an option using bash-style regexes.

```
option       regex        expected result
abc     =~   *a*    -->   match, a is on
abc     =~   *z*    -->   no match, z is off
```

I couldn't identify why it wasn't working properly, but then I found out that this is Bash's behavior:

```
$ [[ "f" =~ *c ]]; echo $?
2                                         # ok
$ [[ "f" =~ *c* ]]; echo $?
2                                         # ok
$ [[ "f" =~ c ]]; echo $?
1                                         # ok
$ [[ "f" =~ c* ]]; echo $?
0                                         # wtf ?
$ [[ "f" =~ f ]]; echo $?
0                                         # ok
$ [[ "f" =~ f* ]]; echo $?
0                                         # ok
$ [[ "f" =~ *f* ]]; echo $?
2                                         # why not ?
$ [[ "f" =~ *f ]]; echo $?
2                                         # same !
```

I thought that `*` would match any string, including the empty string, but this is seriously making me doubt my understanding of regexes...
Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

For the record, `*` used with `ls` gives the expected result:

```
$ echo 1 > f
$ ls
f
$ ls f
f
$ ls *f
f
$ ls *f*
f
$ ls f*
f
$ ls c
ls: cannot access 'c': No such file or directory
$ ls c*
ls: cannot access 'c*': No such file or directory
$ ls *c
ls: cannot access '*c': No such file or directory
$ ls *c*
ls: cannot access '*c*': No such file or directory
```

Comment: @shellter There is a name for the shell pattern matching. It is called **glob**. It is not a simplified regexp. It is it's own language which can be surprisingly more complex than people realise: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/pattern-matching-bash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is perfectly correct for `"f"` to match `c*`. It should also be correct for an empty string to match `c*`. To be specific, what is matching here is the empty string before the character `f`:

```
"f"
^
'----- c* correctly matches here

"f"
 ^
 '---- it is not matching here
```

The regexp pattern `c*` means **zero or more character "c"**.

Obviously, before looking at the character "f", at the beginning of the string, the regexp engine found no character "c". So it matches (no character "c" found matches zero or more character "c").

The following should also match:

```
$ [[ "" =~ *c ]]; echo $?
0
```

---

As for the other results you were not expecting:

```
$ [[ "f" =~ *c ]]; echo $?
2                                         # correctly returns "error"
$ [[ "f" =~ *c* ]]; echo $?
2                                         # correctly returns "error"
$ [[ "f" =~ *f* ]]; echo $?
2                                         # correctly returns "error"
$ [[ "f" =~ *f ]]; echo $?
2                                         # correctly returns "error"
```

Return status `2` in bash signals some error. This is because the pattern `*` on its own is a syntax error in regexp:

```
*f
^
'------ syntax error, expecting something before zero-or-more qualifier (*)
```

The `*` operator in regexp requires you to specify a character to look for. Just `*` on its own makes no sense because you cannot have zero or more of something undefined.

For more info on regular expression syntax used by bash see [A Brief Introduction to Regular Expressions - TLDP](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html)

---

Reading between the lines, you are probably expecting `*` to be a wildcard character. There is a pattern matching language that does that, it is called **glob**. A **regular expression** is a different pattern matching language. You can use **glob** matching in bash using the `==` operator:

```
[[ "f" == *f* ]]
```

Comment: Indeed, [[ "" =~ *c ]] exits with 0, and == seems to have the behavior I was looking for. I can't see why every website I found about regexes decided to leave out that information about the use of == instead of =~...

Comment: @NevenV. Because they are websites about regexp, they obviously won't cover other languages like glob or SQL or graphql. As usual with knowledge, the hardest part is knowing what to search for

Comment: Regexp alone is itself a big topic. It is used in `grep`, bash `=~` operator, `javascript`, `Python`, `C#` etc. And there are different flavours (versions) or regexp from basic regexp, advanced regexp, extended regexp, Perl-compatible regex etc (note that Perl stopped calling it regexp and call it regex because PCRE is no longer a regular language). So regexp websites already have a lot to cover without going into other pattern matching languages like SQL's `%like%` syntax or `glob`

Comment: I know, I maybe that wasn't very clear, but I was refering not to regexes in general, rather to a lesson I found on Bash. You could expect an overview of Bash which presents regexps to at least mention that there is another similar feature.

Comment: @slebetman, ...would you consider cutting over the link from the ABS to a better-maintained reference such as the bash-hackers' wiki page at https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression#regular_expression_matching, or the comparable Wooledge wiki content at https://mywiki.wooledge.org/RegularExpression, or the official manual (which covers `=~` within https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html)?

Comment: Ah. I myself didn't know about the feature (called partial matching). I only found it when answering this question and googling "bash string matching operator" trying to find out the definition of the `=~` operator. The second (or featured) result will give you what you were looking for

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Do you have any link to re_syntax used by bash? I'm not looking for bash syntax, I'm looking for regular expression syntax as implemented by bash. My normal reference is tcl's re_syntax man page but a bash specific page is better in this case

Comment: Bash uses the local standard C library's regex implementation, so there's isn't a canonical spec. It's guaranteed to be compatible with POSIX ERE if the aforementioned C library is implemented to spec (and on some platforms is a superset of that specification), but that's the only guarantee you get.